# Converting string from snake_case to CamelCase in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I am trying to convert a name from snake case to camel case. Are there any built-in methods?

Eg: `"app_user"` to `"AppUser"`

(I have a string `"app_user"` I want to convert that to model `AppUser`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting camel case to underscore case in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509915/converting-camel-case-to-underscore-case-in-ruby)

Answer (score 308, accepted):

If you're using Rails, [String#camelize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-camelize) is what you're looking for.

```
  "active_record".camelize                # => "ActiveRecord"
  "active_record".camelize(:lower)        # => "activeRecord"
```

If you want to get an actual class, you should use [String#constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-constantize) on top of that.

```
"app_user".camelize.constantize
```

Comment: You should add that this is a Rails addition to String, it doesn't work with pure Ruby.

Comment: It's tagged `ruby-on-rails`, so, I guess, it's not a problem. But thanks for mentioning.

Comment: You don't need to camelize before constantizing. Use `#classify` instead. `"some_namespace/module/class_name".classify => "SomeNamespace::Module::ClassName"`

Comment: @chris #classify: Not the same. #classify returns a string, whereas #constantize looks up constant in context (and does need camelize). 'active_record'.constantize gives error, 'active_record'.camelize.constantize returns the constant ActiveRecord, 'active_record'.classify returns the string 'ActiveRecord'. And if you did 'no_class'.camelize.constantize you'd get error (no such constant NoClass), but 'no_class'.classify happily returns 'NoClass' string.

Comment: In order to use these methods of Rails from pure Ruby, `require "active_support/core_ext/string"` is suffice, providing Rails is installed already.

Answer (score 145):

How about this one?

```
"hello_world".split('_').collect(&:capitalize).join #=> "HelloWorld"
```

Found in the comments here:  [Classify a Ruby string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072159/classify-a-ruby-string)

See comment by [Wayne Conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238886/wayne-conrad)

Comment: You are awesome, thank you. I didn't want to have to include rails libraries just for a task this small. This is beautiful. :)

Comment: This is one of the only real answer to the question. Not using Rails libraries.

Answer (score 51):

If you use Rails, Use `classify`. It handles edge cases well.

```
"app_user".classify # => AppUser
"user_links".classify   # => UserLink
```

**Note:**

This answer is specific to the description given in the question(it is not specific to the question title). If one is trying to convert a string to camel-case they should use [Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9524521/163203)'s answer. The questioner states that he wants to convert `app_user` to `AppUser` (not `App_user`), hence this answer..

Comment: For Rails environments, this is perfect.

Comment: Note that `classify` returns a string, you have to call `constantize` afterwards to convert it to an actual class.

Comment: An important caveat with `classify` is that pluralised strings will become singular... `'age_in_years'.classify` becomes `AgeInYear`

Comment: @br3nt it does not pluralize since activerecord `4.2.11`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for me :P. I was looking for this answer.

Answer (score 26):

Source: http://rubydoc.info/gems/extlib/0.9.15/String#camel_case-instance_method

For learning purposes:

```
class String
  def camel_case
    return self if self !~ /_/ && self =~ /[A-Z]+.*/
    split('_').map{|e| e.capitalize}.join
  end
end

"foo_bar".camel_case          #=> "FooBar"
```

And for the lowerCase variant:

```
class String
  def camel_case_lower
    self.split('_').inject([]){ |buffer,e| buffer.push(buffer.empty? ? e : e.capitalize) }.join
  end
end

"foo_bar".camel_case_lower          #=> "fooBar"
```

Comment: @pguardiario if the wheel is called *ActiveSupport*, please reinvent it.

Comment: I think the lowerCase variant is wrong. The inject block should not directly manipulate the buffer but return the new value for the buffer: `self.split('_').inject([]){ |buffer,e| buffer + [buffer.empty? ? e : e.capitalize] }.join`

Answer (score 20):

## Benchmark for pure Ruby solutions

I took every possibilities I had in mind to do it with pure ruby code, here they are :

- capitalize and gsub

  ```
  'app_user'.capitalize.gsub(/_(\w)/){$1.upcase}
  ```
- split and map using `&` shorthand (thanks to user3869936’s answer)

  ```
  'app_user'.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join
  ```
- split and map (thanks to Mr. Black’s answer)

  ```
  'app_user'.split('_').map{|e| e.capitalize}.join
  ```

And here is the Benchmark for all of these, we can see that gsub is quite bad for this. I used 126 080 words.

```
                              user     system      total        real
capitalize and gsub  :      0.360000   0.000000   0.360000 (  0.357472)
split and map, with &:      0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.189493)
split and map        :      0.170000   0.000000   0.170000 (  0.171859)
```

Answer (score 12):

I got here looking for the inverse of your question, going from camel case to snake case. Use [underscore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-underscore) for that (not decamelize):

`AppUser.name.underscore # => "app_user"`

or, if you already have a camel case string:

`"AppUser".underscore # => "app_user"`

or, if you want to get the table name, which is probably why you'd want the snake case:

`AppUser.name.tableize # => "app_users"`

Comment: Why not using `AppUser.table_name`? You will also ensure to have the true table name if it is not app_users, but something defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I feel a little uneasy to add more answers here. Decided to go for the most readable and minimal pure ruby approach, disregarding the nice benchmark from @ulysse-bn. While `:class` mode is a copy of @user3869936, the `:method` mode I don't see in any other answer here.

```
  def snake_to_camel_case(str, mode: :class)
    case mode
    when :class
      str.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join
    when :method
      str.split('_').inject { |m, p| m + p.capitalize }
    else
      raise "unknown mode #{mode.inspect}"
    end
  end
```

Result is:

```
[28] pry(main)> snake_to_camel_case("asd_dsa_fds", mode: :class)
=> "AsdDsaFds"
[29] pry(main)> snake_to_camel_case("asd_dsa_fds", mode: :method)
=> "asdDsaFds"
```

Comment: Camel case is in fact first lower. Otherwise it is named PascalCase (or sometimes upper camel case). Even though in this question it is ambiguous!

Comment: @UlysseBN, tbh I'm not into history of the words. Wikipedia claims `PascalCase` is a subset of `CamelCase`. Also this is what I knew - that camel case applied to both. But I have never investigated. Thanks for mentioning PascalCase though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case

Comment: This is the best answer on the page imo. It would be nice if the `:method` version did a `downcase` first so it can be used on both `lower_snake_case` and `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.

Answer (score 2):

## Extend String to Add Camelize

In pure Ruby you could extend the string class using code lifted from Rails `.camelize`

```
class String
  def camelize(uppercase_first_letter = true)
    string = self
    if uppercase_first_letter
      string = string.sub(/^[a-z\d]*/) { |match| match.capitalize }
    else
      string = string.sub(/^(?:(?=\b|[A-Z_])|\w)/) { |match| match.downcase }
    end
    string.gsub(/(?:_|(\/))([a-z\d]*)/) { "#{$1}#{$2.capitalize}" }.gsub("/", "::")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The ruby core itself has no support to convert a string from snake case to (upper) camel case (also known as pascal case).

So you need either to make your own implementation or use an existing gem.

There is a small ruby gem called **lucky_case** which allows you to convert a string from any of the 10+ supported cases to another case easily:

```
require 'lucky_case'

# to get upper camel case (pascal case) as string
LuckyCase.pascal_case('app_user') # => 'AppUser'
# to get the pascal case constant
LuckyCase.constantize('app_user') # => AppUser
# or the opposite way
LuckyCase.snake_case('AppUser')   # => app_user
```

You can even monkey patch the String class if you want to:

```
require 'lucky_case/string'

'app_user'.pascal_case # => 'AppUser'
'app_user'.constantize # => AppUser
# ...
```

Have a look at the offical repository for more examples and documentation:

https://github.com/magynhard/lucky_case

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other methods listed here are Rails specific. If you want do do this with pure Ruby, the following is the most concise way I've come up with (thanks to @ulysse-bn for the suggested improvement)

```
x="this_should_be_camel_case"
x.gsub(/(?:_|^)(\w)/){$1.upcase}
    #=> "ThisShouldBeCamelCase"
```

Comment: Your definition of "camel case" is too limited. Class names in Java, and Ruby, for example, *are* camel case MyFavoriteClass... but they also don't have a lower cased initial letter. sometimes camel case has initial caps. sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Using 2 Regex where you can use only one is overkill. You can use only non capturing group: `x.gsub(/(?:_|^)(\w)/){$1.upcase}`

Comment: @UlysseBN, and we are back to your `gsub` solution it seems which is slower compared to the `map` solution.

Comment: It's not complicated:

camelCase has a lowercase first character.

PascalCase has an uppercase first character.

I blame rails for having a camelize method which defaults to returning PascalCase.

https://apidock.com/rails/String/camelize

Comment: While you may be technically or historically correct Darren, the community does not make that distinction. For example, Java class names have upper case first letters and, in almost every article / post that mentions it the convention is called "camel case", even those written long before Rails. Lower first  letters are also described as "camel case" essentially everywhere. Both are "camel case" by the modern definition.