# Convert Sentence to Camelcase in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This seems like it would be ridiculously easy, but I can't find a method anywhere, to convert a sentence string/hyphenated string to camelcase.

```
Ex:
'this is a sentence' => 'thisIsASentence'
'my-name' => 'myName'
```

Seems overkill to use regex. What's the best way?

Comment: Have you tried any sort of a loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524457/converting-string-from-snake-case-to-camel-case-in-ruby

Comment: @JustinWood the issue isn't doing it, it's finding the best way with the fewest lines of code.

Comment: @bredikhin That's from `snake case`, not `sentence case`

Comment: @ElijahMurray *the best way* is not necessarily *with the fewest lines of code*. Keep that in mind.

Comment: @ElijahMurray You're right, my bad. Though you can always do something like `'this is a sentence'.gsub('-', ' ').gsub(' ', '_').camelize(:lower)`.

Answer (score 10):

```
> s = 'this is a sentence'
 => "this is a sentence"
> s.gsub(/\s(.)/) {|e| $1.upcase}
 => "thisIsASentence"
```

You'd need to tweak that regexp to match on dashes in additions to spaces, but that's easy.

Pretty sure there's a regexp way to do it as well without needing to use the block form, but I didn't look it up.

Comment: Yeah, this works, but it seems like so much overkill. There's a `dasherize` method, as well as an `underscore` method. Is there anything similar that catches spaces?

Comment: I doubt it.  Go look at the Rails source for these (and camelize) methods.  It's the same thing, they just wrapped it up nice.

Answer (score 4):

Using Rails' ActiveSupport, the following works for both cases:

```
"this is a sentence".underscore.parameterize("_").camelize(:lower)
# => "thisIsASentence"

"my-name".underscore.parameterize("_").camelize(:lower)
# => "myName"
```

the `underscore` converts any dashes, and the `parameterize` converts the spaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `ActiveSupport` (for instance because of Rails or any other dependency), then have a look at the [`ActiveSupport::Inflector`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) module. These methods are immediately available to you for any `String`.

```
'egg_and_hams'.classify # => "EggAndHam"
'posts'.classify        # => "Post"
```

Keep in mind that the standard separator in Ruby is the `_`, not the `-`. It means you probably need to replace it.

```
'my-name'.tr('-', '_').classify
 => "MyName" 
'my-name'.tr('-', '_').camelize(:lower)
 => "myName"
```

Using ActiveSupport is just delegating the job. Keep in mind that, behind the scenes, these conversions in Ruby are very likely to be performed using regular expressions.

In fact, in Ruby regexp are cheap and very common.

Answer (score 3):

```
'this is a sentence'.split.map.with_index { |x,i| i == 0 ? x : x.capitalize  }.join # => "thisIsASentence"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [String#camelize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-camelize)

```
"test_string".camelize(:lower)           # => "testString"
```

If you're using other separators than underscore, use the `gsub` method to substitute other characters to underscores before camelizing.

Comment: No, I'm not. If you do `"test string".camelize(:lower)` it returns `"test string"`

Comment: If you're using other separaters than underscore, you can use the gsub method to substitute other characters to underscores before camelizing.