# Ruby capitalize is not working inside the map method

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to turn the first letters of a string into uppercase characters. I am trying to turn:

```
"this is a test sentence"
```

into:

```
"This Is A Test Sentence"
```

Here is my code:

```
def first_upper(str)
  arr_str = str.split
  arr_str.map do |item|
    item.capitalize
  end
  arr_str = arr_str.join(' ')
  puts arr_str
end

first_upper('this is a test sentence')
# >> this is a test sentence
```

`item.capitalize` works inside the `map` loop if I put pry's `binding.pry` there.

Am I not using the `map` method correctly?

Comment: Try with `map!`

Comment: Ahh, so I was creating an array with map, but not assigning it to anything. map! replaces the elements of the original array. Thank you!

Comment: What you are saying: "turn the first letters of a string into uppercase characters" and what you are expecting are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ´map´ method does not mutate it's receiver, instead it returns a new modified copy of it. You can either use it's mutative/destructive counterpart `map!` or just reassign the value of the expression to the variable.

```
arr_str.map! do |item|
  item.capitalize
end

# ... or ...

arr_str = arr_str.map do |item|
  item.capitalize
end
```

Comment: There's a third option: mutate the strings themselves, with `item.capitalize!`. (Although, if you're not sure where things are reused, the non-destructive `arr_str = ...` way is the safest.)

Answer (score 2):

It "doesn't work" as you expect to do it. As capitalize applies the capitalize method on item, the receiver, and then returns a new representation of your `arr_str` yielding what's inside the block. In other words and as the doc states:

> map { |obj| block } → array click to toggle source 
>   map → an_enumerator 
>   Returns a new array with the results of running block once for every
>   element in enum.

Your `arr_str` would be modified if you use a "persistent" method to do so, like the map's brother, [`Array#map!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map-21), which works slightly different:

> map! {|item| block } → ary click to toggle source 
>   map! → Enumerator 
>   Invokes the given block once for each element of self, replacing the element with the value returned by the block.

What your code is doing right now, is spliting the string passed, iterating over each element within the generated and stored result of split, and applying capitalize on those elements, and finally joining them and printing them with puts:

```
def first_upper(str)
  arr_str = str.split         # ["this", "is", "a", "test", "sentence"]

  arr_str.map do |item|
    item.capitalize
  end                         # ["This", "Is", "A", "Test", "Sentence"]

  arr_str = arr_str.join(' ') # this is a test sentence
  puts arr_str                # this is a test sentence
end

first_upper('this is a test sentence')
```

The most simple and evident approaches are:

A) To store the result of `arr_str.map` in a variable to be used within the function after that step.
B) To use map! and this way modify arr_str and "persists" what's being done within that block.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my two cents..

These are some ways, monkey patched into `String` class.

```
module MyStringPatch

  def titleize_1
    split(' ').collect(&:capitalize).join(' ') # Stolen from user3869936
  end

  def titleize_2
    gsub(/\b(?<!['â`])[a-z]/) { |match| match.capitalize } # Stolen from Rails
  end

 def titleize_3
   split.map { |item| item.capitalize }.join(' ') # Stolen from OP: user4396386
 end

end

String.include MyStringPatch

string = "this is a test sentence"

p string.titleize_1 # => "This Is A Test Sentence"
p string.titleize_2 # => "This Is A Test Sentence"
p string.titleize_3 # => "This Is A Test Sentence"
```

#### Credits:

- `titleize_1` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24917606/5239030
- `titleize_2` from Rails:
  https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize
- `titleize_3` from OP: [Ruby capitalize is not working inside the map method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52088306/5239030)