# Converting snake case to normal sentence in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to convert a string in snake case to normal case(Eg: "hello_world" to "Hello world")

I'm pretty new to ruby, and I'm using it with Rails. I found this question [Converting string from snake_case to CamelCase in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524457/converting-string-from-snake-case-to-camelcase-in-ruby/39716710), and it seems like there is a function for that usecase (`.camelize`). Is there anything that I can use inbuilt like that? If not, how can I achieve this?

Comment: did you also look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11411200/8340945

Comment: Looks like it can be modded to the purpose, but I prefer something more precise.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[humanize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/String.html#method-i-humanize) is your thing:

```rb
[4] pry(main)> "hello_world".humanize
"Hello world"
```

Comment: This requires Rails.

Answer (score 12):

Rails has a method called [`titleize`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize)

```
"hello_world".titleize # => "Hello World"
```

Ruby has a method called [`capitalize`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/capitalize)

```
"hello_world".capitalize # => "Hello_world"
```

If you want "Hello world" with only the "H" capitalized, combine them both (in Rails).

```
"hello_world".titleize.capitalize # => "Hello world"
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I do `> "hello_world".titleize` I get `"Hello_world"` with Rails 5.2. However `.humanize` does the trick (see below).

Answer (score 4):

```
"hello_world".capitalize.gsub("_"," ")
=> "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5 brought in a new `upcase_first` method:
https://glaucocustodio.github.io/2016/05/19/rails-5-new-upcase-first-method/

Combine this with subbing all underscores with spaces and you should be good:

```
text = 'hello_world'

text.upcase_first.gsub('_', ' ')
=> 'Hello world'
```

Comment: shouldn't it be like this for camel case? text.upcase_first.gsub('_', '')